# Transferring installed applications from one computer to another in ubuntu

Tags: vlc, transfer

I'm sorry, this is obviously a duplicate. But other posts were not helpful.

I have Ubuntu 13.04 running on my laptop. My friend has VLC in his Ubuntu 12.04. And I want to copy VLC to my laptop. I have no `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed. And my friends `/var/cache/apt/archives` folder is empty. Maybe it is because he installed VLC using Software Center.

So is there any way to copy VLC to my laptop from my friends laptop, so that I can watch videos too? :)

(Internet cost is expensive here :|)
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please help! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to delete this, but as it is an accepted answer, it did not succeed. Therefore please downvote or, better, change the accepted answer and brutally delete this post if possible.**

While it is probably helpful to understand how Ubuntu packaging system works, for the particular task it is just better to use a proper tool and not mess up with hacks that might (especially if badly executed) mess up your system. Refer to the other answer mentioning `dpkg-repack` and check if that would solve the problem.

**(Old anwer removed.)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use **dpkg-repack** tool for this task.

Install dpkg-repack:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack
```

Example usage:

```
sudo dpkg-repack vlc
```

Replace *vlc* with your package name.

For more info see: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dpkg-repack.1

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head, and probably not the answer your after, maybe you can check your friend's cache/apt folder and if you're lucky enough find the VLC package there. Besides, I'm not even sure about it, but maybe only copying the VLC files alone won't do you any good if you don't have the codecs and stuff it needs, in case their not in between those files.

Comment: is it possible to copy just codecs?

Comment: I hope it won't hurt but I think you can just give it a try and copy/paste every trace of your friend's vlc to the same path in your Ubuntu, and just sit down and pray. Maybe something as naive as `find -name vlc` and same for the codecs, and who knows, stupid things happen, but rarely of course if they're good.